# Why does ga:clientId dimension request return empty array when using python3 google analytics v4?

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, clientid

Trying to get clientId from google analytics currently via python code:

```
def get_report(analytics):
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            "reportRequests": [
                {
                    "viewId": VIEW_ID,
                    "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "7daysAgo", "endDate": "today"}],
                    "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:pagePath"}, {"name": "ga:clientId"}],
                    "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:pageViews"}, {"expression": "ga:sessions"},
                                {"expression": "ga:avgTimeOnPage"}]
                }]
        }
    ).execute()
```

this code returns empty array, if I remove:

```
{"name": "ga:clientId"}
```

It works fine, and returns all the data. Also using Java, I can get the clientID number fine in such fashion:

```
Dimension clientId = new Dimension().setName("ga:clientId"); 

ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
        .setViewId(VIEW_ID)
        .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
        .setMetrics(lstMetrics)
        .setDimensions(lstDim);

    ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
    requests.add(request);

    // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
    GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
        .setReportRequests(requests);

    // Call the batchGet method.
    GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();

    // Return the response.
    return response;
```

But python fails to produce same data response.